# how to add an scroll to a JTabbedPane

Tags: java, scroll, tabs

I'm very oxided with my java, and the few times that I need to make a GUI always I had used windowbuilder in eclipse, but I want to create an plugin for cytoscape, which works with java.

At this time I have a jframe with a jtabbedpane (with 2 tabs). So in the second tab I want to add elements "out" of the original size of the frame, by this reason I added a jscrollpane (including the setPreferredSize() ), but when adding elements out of the margin nothing is visible, So I'm not understanding something.
For this reason my question is which is the best way to make a panel with a down-side scroll?

This is my base code

```
package org.cytoscape.sample.internal;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;



public class GUI {

    JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUI window = new GUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public GUI() {
        initialize();
    }


    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame("simple test");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 415, 650);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        
        JMenu mnNewMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(mnNewMenu);
        
        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Manual");
        mnNewMenu.add(mntmNewMenuItem);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        tabbedPane.setBounds(0, 0, 415, 530);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);
        
        /**********************************
        *
        * Here start the first tab
        *
        ***********************************/    
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("first tab", null, mainPanel, null);

        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        
        
        
        /**********************************
        *
        * Here start the second tab
        *
        ***********************************/

        JScrollPane configPanelHM = new JScrollPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("second tab", null, configPanelHM, null);
        configPanelHM.setLayout(null);
        
        configPanelHM.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));

    
        
        /**********************************
        *
        * Run Button
        *
        ***********************************/
        JButton btnRunWeon = new JButton("Run");
        btnRunWeon.setBounds(0, 535, 409, 47);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnRunWeon);

    }
}
```